# How to make Green circle/square like animation indicating user's remaining time in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

How to animate a line as in the attached image below, to show that user's time is running out? 
 I used **rotate_point.xml** to animate a **point image** setting 
`<rotate 
 android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"android:toDegrees="360" />` 
 but the problem is that it shows the final animated position only, i.e. it doesn't draw the whole line. 
[The game from which the screenshot was taken is here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miniclip.eightballpool&hl=en), for better understanding of what this animation does.

Is there a better way to  create and handle this animation??

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: the highlighted green line that moves around]

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the [Property Animation System](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)? It can only be used on Android 3.0+.

The main idea, but you can read the reference by yourself for a better understanding, is that you can 'animate' every property of a generic Object you have defined. You can design your own Interpolator which draws your object according to how much time has passed and how you want to be drawn at that particular time fraction (i.e. I want my rectangle to be half green and half black when animation time reaches the 50%).

There are infinite possibilities and combination in this kind of animations so you must find your own way if you think this is the best solution to your problem. Good luck / work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i think i didn't make myself clear here. Those Property Animation System is what used to animate the xml,as here 
 `ImageView point = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.point_img);
Animation PointTurn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_point);
point.startAnimation(PointTurn);` 
 But they only animate the xml view, but i want to **draw** along with animation.